# Initialize variable with custom value of dynamic shape

Tags: tensorflow

I want to initialize one `tf.Variable` with a custom `np.array` of *dynamic shape*. How should I define the variable? How do I initialize it with custom array while within the session? I cannot make it a placeholder, because then I have to feed the matrix everytime I run a batch, whereas I need a one-time initialization?

Another thing is that when I will load the model from metagraph for inference, I would be needing to initialize the same weight with a different array of different shape.

Comment: Can you add to your post a very simple example of code which illustrates your problem? It is not clear to me what you mean by "`np.array` of dynamic shape" (in this context).

Comment: Furthermore, what do you mean exactly by a "one-time initialization"?

Comment: The `tf.Variable` class has `assign` and `set_shape` methods.